# Why would printing a certain string cause the code to execute twice?

Tags: php

I'm creating an email by loading in dynamically generated html from a php view file, but when the following html is included the code seems to execute twice.
    `<table background="#000">`
(I'm not even sure if the `background="#000"` attribute is valid but that shouldn't matter in this context)

Here is a simplified example to demonstrate the issue.

```
$body = '<table background="#000">';

print $body;

$handle = fopen('error.log', 'a');
fwrite($handle, '########################'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."########################\n".$body."\n\n");
fclose($handle);
```

This will generate 2 lines of text in the log file (It should only generate 1).
(I am using `a` as the second parameter for `fopen` so that the second write is appended. The `error.log` file will have to be manually deleted before reloading the page.)

If `print $body;` is commented out or removed then the log file only has 1 line written to it.

If I change the `#000` to any non hex value (e.g. red), or change `table` to anything else (e.g. div), or if I change the `background` attribute to anything else the log file only has 1 line written to it.

I have tried this on 2 different servers running PHP 5.6.12 and 5.5.9, and Apache 2.4.7 and 2.4.16.

Comment: works as expected for me

Comment: I just tried the same code on a third server and got the same results. However, I did notice that adding `style="background:#000"` after the `background` attribute causes it to work correctly.

Comment: you expect a date, a line break, the `<table background="#000">` and 2 more line breaks per execution - correct?

Comment: @Dagon correct. However, what I'm getting is that output twice. Here is a screenshot of my log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/8iwf5oil7wx6skq/Screenshot%202015-09-29%2015.34.46.png?dl=0

Comment: odd works for me, 2 servers tested. how are you executing the code?

Comment: I have been executing it in a browser. I just tried it from the command line and it works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: The browser treats `background="#000"` as a background image attribute, using the relative URL of `#000` as the image's source, causing the page to be loaded twice.**

When the browser makes the request to the PHP file, it receives the following back:

```
<table background="#000">
```

The browser tries to parse the malformed HTML document by cleaning it up, turning it into this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table background="#000"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Nothing exciting or unexpected with that. What is interesting though, is the `background` attribute in the `table` tag. If you inspect the page in Chrome's devtools and you look at the style of the table, you will notice that the table has the following CSS applied (if the page is located at `http://example.com/index.html`:

```
background-image: url('http://example.com/index.html#000');
```

It turns out that the background attribute used to be valid on `table` tags (among a few others), but has since been made [obsolete in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-background).

> When a `table`, `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`, `tr`, `td`, or `th` element has a background attribute set to a non-empty value, the new value is expected to be resolved relative to the element, and if this is successful, the user agent is expected to treat the attribute as a presentational hint setting the element's 'background-image' property to the resulting absolute URL.

[HTML5 Spec, Section 10.3.9 (Tables)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html)

What is happening is that `#000` is being treated as a relative URL, so the browser is making a second request to the exact same URL (the URL sent over the network does not contain the hash string).

Comment: Nice catch. Been a long time since I've even seen `background`, let alone thought about it.